# Java basic 'if' statement parsing

Tags: java, if-statement

So, let's say that in a method I have the following if statement:

```
String displayName = e.getPlayer().getInventory().getItemInMainHand().getItemMeta().getDisplayName();
if(displayName.equals(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&9&lDiamond Golem Spawner")))
{ // }
```

How can I create a sort of 'shortcut' to shorten the above code in this way for instance:

```
if(displayName.customEquals("&9&lDiamond Golem Spawner")))
{ // }
```

In order to automatically imply that my `customEquals` is actually: `equals(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', arg))`

Comment: Add a method `customEquals`

Comment: You cannot add methods to built-in classes.

Comment: Can't you just create a function called `customEquals`? Then just pass both arguments in instead of one of them being implicitly `this`.

Comment: @SLaks you can define a method `customEquals` which takes two `String` arguments

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is imposible so you can create a method in your class called customEquals called this way:

```
 if(customEquals(displayName,"&9&lDiamond Golem Spawner""){
    //your code
 }
```

And the method:

```
public boolean customEquals(String displayName, String string){

return displayName.equals(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', string));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java, that is not possible. a [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) is a built-in class that will not allow you to add your own methods to it, and in addition it is also a `final` class, so it won't allow you to subclass it either.

What you can do is to add a method to your own class(es) doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a static method:

```
static boolean customEquals(String a, String b) {
    return a.equals(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', b));
}
```

Then in your code write

```
if(customEquals(displayName, "&9&lDiamond Golem Spawner")) {}
```